# Non sudoers cannot ssh to Ubuntu machine?

Tags: ssh, root, connection, timeout

When logged as sudoer on machine A (Raspbian 8.0) I can ssh to machine B (Ubuntu LTS 16.04.2), but as non sudoer on machine A I get : connection timed out.

Tough I can ssh other machines inside or outside the local network when logged as a non sudoer on machine A.
Moreover I can ssh machine B to A as a non sudoer, and then ssh A to B as non sudoer through a reverse tunnel.

Don't understand why I can't ssh A to B as a non sudoer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe worth looking into /etc/ssh/sshd_config on machine B. Maybe when it was set up, it was set up only for a specific user? Scroll to bottom of the sshd_config file and look for **AllowUsers**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: `AllowUsers` would not cause connection timeout.

Comment: As far as I know AllowUsers has absolutely no effect over the sshing user, it only defines under which user name  you are allowed to log in in the machine you are sshing into.
Anyway, there is nothing such as AllowUsers or DenyUsers in the machine B sshd_config file.

Comment: As Jakuje said, I was wrong about AllowUsers. It will not return a Connection Timeout - anything around sshd config that blocks users or authentication more likely to return Connection Refused. Have you tried ***"-v' Verbose mode. Causes ssh to print debugging messages about its progress. This is helpful in debugging connection, authentication, and configuration problems. Multiple -v options increase the verbosity. The maximum is 3."*** From ssh man? Maybe the output of that might get a few more troubleshooters interested. Any other details you can provide?

Comment: Yes I did : 
<pre>ssh  -vvv 198.168.0.31
    OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to 198.168.0.31 [198.168.0.31] port 22.<code>

<pre>connection timed out<code>

Comment: "Unfortunately" I can no more reproduce the issue, for some unknown reason, now I can log as non sudoer to machine B.